# How to migrate/send Outlook rules to Office 365?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

When I create a rule in Outlook (POP3) then the rule only applies only when using Outlook.

If I create a rule in Office 365 then the rule is also applied to Outlook.

Is there a workaround to migrate/send the rules from Outlook to Office 365?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want the rules created for account a to be applied to account B as well?
Or do you want to migrate rules in different Outlook profiles or Outlook clients?

As I know, we can easily migrate rules by importing and exporting rules. Just go to ***File>Info>Manage Rules & Alerts>Options***, choose ***Export Rules*** and then import the rules to the account you want in the same location.

[image]

[image]

For more information, please refer to: **[Import or export a set of rules](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-or-export-a-set-of-rules-f54b5bd2-40e0-426e-9f25-e51fa14eeb95)**.

Comment: Hi Thanks, i want to migrate the client rules from outlook to 0365

Comment: What do you mean about "Outlook" and "O365" ? Are they Outlook desktop clients or accounts?

Comment: Hi, i want to migrate the rules from outlook desktop client to office 365.

Comment: Then you can try the importing and exporting method I mentioned above. Export in Outlook desktop client and import in Office365.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.